# How can I append a header row into by output of my Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am producing an output CSV file with a Dataflow and I'd like to write a header row and then append all of my output to that. How can I go about doing that?

My flow roughly looks like this:

```
    PCollection<String> output = data.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            // Produce CSV output
        }
    })).apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteData").to(options.getOutput()));
```

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer below to mention the custom sink API, which is the definitive answer to your question now.

Comment: Are you writing the output CSV to google cloud storage?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to use the [Custom Sink API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sinks). You can derive from `FileBasedSink`, `FileBasedWriteOperation` and `FileBasedWriter` (for example, you can name your classes respectively `CSVSink`, `CSVWriteOperation` and `CSVWriter`).

The only non-trivial logic will be in `CSVWriter`. Write the header in its `writeHeader()` and write the CSV entries in `write()`.

Then you can use the sink in the pipeline using the `Write.to()` transform, in place of `TextIO` you're currently using.

A good example built into the SDK is [the XML sink](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/XmlSink.java).

Comment: In the case that there's more data than the memory can handle then the only way would be to partition the PCollection and end up with several CSV files, right?

Comment: I rewrote this answer, this comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the header from `DoFn#startBundle()`.

Comment: Marian - does Dataflow guarantee that it will execute it only once?

Comment: I did a simple test to add output data into the context during the startBundle() and it did not end up as the first element in the PCollection result and subsequently was not the line of the file. I think using the Combine transform may be what I'm looking for. I'll post my solution once it is correct.

Comment: You're right, my solution doesn't work if the transform overriding startBundle() isn't running in the same stage as the TextIO.Write transform. While that would happen today if it's the last transform before the write and you don't specify the number of output shards explicitly, it is not guaranteed.